# CSS text-align for other stuff than text (like buttons)

Tags: css, alignment, text-align

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp) the property is used to "align text within elements".

When using it in different ways however, like buttons, it also works perfectly. See [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p97Pe/)

Is it a good idea to use the align-text CSS property in situations like this or is something else a better solution like putting `float: right` on the button?

I was wondering if this attribute was intended only for text or if the name was just chosen poorly.

(as pointed out by Ray Toal, the answer is in [the official W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-text-20030514/#alignment-prop))

Comment: Oh noes!  You linked to the W3 *Schools* description of the property, NOT the W3C's specification!  They are not the same thing at all! The W3C spec is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-text-20030514/#alignment-prop).  You can see it aligns inline elements within their block, just as the accepted answer states.  [Beware of W3Schools](http://w3fools.com/)!

Comment: @RayToal that was indeed a bad mistake to make. I didn't know W3Schools had nothing to do with W3C. Thanks for pointing out that I should avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be more accurate, it is used to align text *and inline elements* within their parents.

So spans, buttons, elements with `display:inline-block` and so on will be aligned according to `text-align`, whereas block-level elements are unaffected (but may inherit the container's `text-align` and apply it to further descendants).

Comment: Okay, so it's for text and anything that is also inline. Thanks. I wonder why they didn't call it "horizontal-align" or simply "align" then, like the attribute name that can be used in html elements (I know that is really bad though)

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `text-align` is perfectly fine here. Using floats would then need to clear following elements from their effects, etc

Perfectly fine: I wouldn't say that of the HTML code of your example (table, no label, no for/id association)

Comment: Haha, I just whipped up some random HTML quickly to have some sort of context for my question. Don't worry, I'm not **that** bad when I use html in production environment :)